# Problem with lombok when compile with inteliJ

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I would like to compile my project. It works fine with command mvn clean install -U , but when I try to build it with intelij or run tests InteliJ throws :

```
java: Lombok visitor handler class lombok.javac.handlers.HandleVal failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol.isLocal()'
```

I tried:

- remove .idea
- remove .m2
- invalidate caches
- mvn idea:idea / mvn clean:idea
- processing annotation is on and lombok plugin is installed

This problem occurs in some microservices.

Do you know a solution ?

In project (parent) Pom.xml dependency :

```
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
...
        <lombok.version>1.18.10</lombok.version>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

In services pom.xml:

```
        <path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </path>
```

Comment: Please mention the dependency also that you are using for lombok in pom.xml

Comment: Yes, this sounds like trying to use an older lombok jar when compiling on a newer release of `javac`.

Comment: The JAR you're using for Lombok contains a class that doesn't have that method.  Looks like 1.18.24 is the latest version.  Try upgrading.

Comment: I have updated my question about some content from pom.xml.

Comment: It;s interesting that when i change version of lomobok over 1.16.12 it's even not compile with mvn due to problem with mapping ... But in version 1.16.12 I get same erros (as version over 1.16.12 in mvn) in inteliJ... java: Unknown property "averageTimeInSeconds" in result type XXXX. Did you mean "null"?   CODE of mapping use mapstruct - > @Mappings({
   @Mapping(target = "averageTimeInSeconds", source = "averageTimeInSeconds"),
 })

Answer (score 2):

Error can happen when there is **JDK version mismatch**. E.g. sources are compiled with pom.xml and have a jdk11 version, but IDEA project has jdk17 configured. I switched between branches with 11 and 17 and forgot to change settings.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find a little strange solution on this error... I have changed Project settings -> project sdk version from 1.7(Version of project in pom.xml) to  version with path which my mvn command have used (mvn --version jdk):
Java version: 11.0.12, vendor: Eclipse Foundation, runtime: .\Local\Programs\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot .
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may concern: I had this exact error, in this case it was another IntelliJ module that I wasn't paying attention to which was causing the problem (as IntelliJ did not state which module, I had assumed it was the one I was working on and changing). Try:

- Removing all modules that you aren't working on
- Upgrading Lombok to the latest version